# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. JSON Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I am fairly new to the Rails world and wanted to creat another project to play around with some code. Upon running 'rails new myproject', I ran into this error. I searched around Google for a solution with no luck. How can I get past this issue to proceed with the creation of my Rails app when I run 'bundle install'?

I'm running: 
OSX 10.7.5 
Rails 3.1.1 
Ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]

> Using coffee-script (2.2.0)  Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)  Installing json
>   (1.8.0) with native extensions  Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError:
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb  creating Makefile
>
> make xcrun cc -I.
>   -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin11.0
>   -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin11.0
>   -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O3 -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   -c generator.c Error: No developer directory found at /Developer. Run /usr/bin/xcode-select to update the
>   developer directory path. make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/me/.bundler/tmp/1673/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /Users/me/.bundler/tmp/1673/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
>   An error occured while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

I noticed this line but don't know quite what this means..
Error: No developer directory found at /Developer. Run /usr/bin/xcode-select to update the developer directory path.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run xcode-select?

Comment: I do not believe so. How do I do this and where?

Comment: From your error message : `Error: No developer directory found at /Developer. Run /usr/bin/xcode-select to update the developer directory path.` - you need this from anywhere : `/usr/bin/xcode-select`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install "Command Line Tools" from preferences in Xcode 4.

Comment: Command Line Tools is not installed. I am downloading now. Hope this fixes the issue! I will update once it is done..

Comment: This did not work. I have updated my original post with the error message I got now incase it is different in some way.